# Deleting rows in Spreadsheet with any input in the row

Tags: rows

I need a macro that will delete all the rows in my spreadsheet, (between row 28, and the next empty row below row 28), that have ANY input in any cells in that row.

I want to start the deletion process from row 28 and stop where it reaches a row with no input (All cells in that row are Blank ).

THANKS!

Comment: It would be slightly easier to answer if you would provide the target of the process, Is it a database, a file, a spreadsheet, a prison dormitory,  what? and what is the schema of the data?

Comment: Hello Charles. the data is in a spreadsheet. I made a macro that inserts new rows each time when you look for an ID. However if you enter another ID, the newly added lines will add up to the previously added lines. So what I want to do is to "reset" the code by deleting the newly added lines. All the lines are added below row 28. So I want to delete all rows with input below that row. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edited your question to add more details. Please verify that it is accurate, and specify what spreadsheet product you are using (Excel, what?)